# Uploading screen shots to itunes connect for app: error message wrong dimmensions for ipad

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

When uploading screen shots to iTunes connect for app: error message "wrong dimensions" for 12.9" iPad keeps coming up. The pixels dimensions look correct, 2048 x 1536.  I was able to upload all other iPhone and iPad-mini sizes with no problem at all.  I re-checked image size, and it seems fine.  Very frustrating.

Help please!

Here is a link to the image:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bwz6l_HXJf2VTUxIQlF4SHdEdUk/view?usp=sharing

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On iTunes Connect Properties, it says "9.7-Inch Retina Display Screenshots (may use 12.9-inch Display)". It means you can upload 12.9 screenshot for iPad. Not the other way around. You can't upload normal iPad screenshot for 12.9

If you just want to upload normal iPad screenshot, click the bottom button `Media Manager`
[image]

Then you can scroll down, find `9.7-Inch Display` where you can upload screenshot `2048x1536`
[image]